# Evento OnChange jQuery HTML

Tags: jquery, html

No logro que al seleccionar una opción que no sea la primera se envie correctamente el parámetro a la función `Export()`. El `alert` me lo tira correctamente con la opción que selecciono. Pero a la hora de enviar el parámetro siempre envía el primero.

Formulario:

```js
  var a = $("#paquetes option:selected" ).text();
    $('#paquetes').on('change', function() {
      alert( this.value );
      var a = $("#paquetes option:selected" ).text();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="paquetes" class="selectpicker" onchange="">
    <optgroup label="Seleccionar paquete a exportar">
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>

    
  

     <button onclick="Export(a)" id="enviar" class="btn btn-success">Exportar a Excel</button>
```

Todo esto está dentro de un form.

Comment: Muestranos la funcion `Export` que no esta definida en tu ejemplo

Comment: Y de paso muestra que mensaje lanza el `alert`, y si algo lánzalo por consola  ver que te aparece, si algún `object` o un `undfined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes quitar la palabra reservada `var` al querer asignar un nuevo valor a la varible global `a`. El problema es que estás definiendo una variable local (dentro del ámbito de la función) con el mismo nombre de una variable global, es decir, que estás inicializando dos variables con el mismo nombre en vez de asignarle un valor a la variable global que ya creaste. Por eso mismo siempre envía como argumento la primer opción del select, porque nunca se sobreescribe el valor de la variable `a` con el del `option` seleccionado.

```js
  function Export(a) {
      console.log("Argumento: " + a);
  }

  var a = $("#paquetes option:selected" ).text();
    $('#paquetes').on('change', function() {
      // Para asignar un nuevo valor a la variable global "a" no se usa var, 
      // solo el nombre de la variable
      a = $("#paquetes option:selected" ).text();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="paquetes" class="selectpicker" onchange="">
    <optgroup label="Seleccionar paquete a exportar">
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<button onclick="Export(a)" id="enviar" class="btn btn-success">Exportar a Excel</button>
```

Comment: Ese era el problema. Una doble declaración var de la variable a, quedó solucionado quitando el var dentro del Onchange como mencionaste. Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Marco respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres ligarlo a presionar un botón, puedes escuchar el `onclick` del botón. Pero es necesario darle otro id a tu botón, no es recomendable tener dos elementos con el mismo id. En este caso le ha dado el id `btn`.

```js
$(function() 
{
  
  
  //Escuchando el botón mediante su id (btn)
  $("#btn").click(function() 
  {
      var a = $("#paquetes option:selected" ).text();
      alert("Valor es: "+a);
  });


  //La acción se puede lanzar desde aquí si se quiere
  //a no ser que haga falta otro dato o verificación antes de lanzarla

  $('#paquetes').on('change', function() 
  {
      alert("La acción se puede lanzar aquí, ¿por qué no? "+ this.value );
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="paquetes" class="selectpicker" onchange="">
    <optgroup label="Seleccionar paquete a exportar">
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>

     <button id="btn" class="btn btn-success">Exportar a Excel</button>
```

También, puedes lanzar la acción en el `onchange` tal y como lo tienes actualmente, sólo que en ese caso debes mostrar una opción predefinida con un mensaje como `--Seleccione opción--`, de lo contrario no podrías enviar `A` a la primera si lo desearas, y tendrías que controlar que esa opción predefinida nunca se envíe.